# Is it possible to disable prompt for collection_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I use:

```
<%= f.collection_select :parent_id, Parent.all, :id, :title, prompt: true %>
```

Then Rails generates:

```
<select  name="child[parent_id]" id="child_parent_id">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">Parent#1</option>
  ...
</select>
```

But I want to disable prompt:

```
<option value="" disable>Please select</option>
```

Is there an attribute which disables it?

**I don't want to remove it. I want to disable it**

Comment: what did you try? research? `prompt: false` or removing that prompt option completley,?

Comment: I don't want to remove it. I want to disable it

Comment: Did you try `:disabled => "disabled"` ?

Answer (score 0):

`prompt` will provide an input value, `include_blank` will not.

```
ìnclude_blank: 'fill this field out or you shall not pass...'
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove `prompt` option and add `include_blank: false` instead of it. It should remove 'Please select' option.

Comment: The goal is to leave it, but make it disabled